# How to unrar file with password hidden inside rar file as text?

Tags: text, passwords, rar, unrar

There is rar file with password-protected that I need to extract, but the password to extract is in a text file inside that rar file. How can I extract it without using brute-force method because the password is complicated?

Answer (score 1):

If the password to extract the rar file is inside the rar file, you cannot extract it without cracking the password. What you're asking to do is impossible.